# The probability of getting at least 3 same dice in a 5 dice roll

Tags: probability

I know that the probability of getting the 3 dice to be of the specific same number in a 3 dice roll is `(1/6)*(1/6)*(1/6) = 1/216`. What is the probability of getting the same specific number for 3 dice in a 5 dice roll?

Do we calculate that with adding the probabilities for 3 of the same dice with 4 and 5 of the same dice together?

Something like this:

```
P(three or more dice show the same number) = P(3) + P(4) + P(5)
```

Which then would be:

```
P = (1/6)*(1/6)*(1/6) + (1/6)*(1/6)*(1/6)*(1/6) + (1/6)*(1/6)*(1/6)*(1/6)*(1/6)
P = 0.00552983539
```

Is that the correct way of calculating the probability for such case?

Comment: *dice* is plural; *die* is singular

Comment: Do not confuse yourself with what $P(3)$ represents.  In a different problem, $P(3)$ might have been the probability that when rolling three dice that all three came up as $1$'s and would have occurred with probability $\frac{1}{6}\times\frac{1}{6}\times\frac{1}{6}$.  However, in *this* problem, $P(3)$ as you call it would have meant something else, namely that when rolling *five* dice that exactly three of the five dice came up as the same number, whatever number that happened to be while the remaining dice are whatever other number and in whatever position from those five rolls.

Answer (score 2):

Your question falls under the category of [binomial probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution). Since you're asking for 'at least 3...' you should look at the pdf of the binomial distribution.

**Step 1: Why is it binomial?** reference: [Yale](http://www.stat.yale.edu/Courses/1997-98/101/binom.htm)

```
1: The number of observations n is fixed.
2: Each observation is independent.
3: Each observation represents one of two outcomes ("success" or "failure").
4: The probability of "success" $p$ is the same for each outcome.
```

**Step 2: the equation:**

$${n\choose k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$$

**Step 3: setup the data:**

> \begin{align}n&=5\\ k&=3\\ p&=\frac16\\ 1-p&=\frac56\end{align}

**Step 3: plug in**

$${5 \choose 3}* \left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^3*\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^2=0.032$$

**Step 4: Cumulative probability:$P(X \geq x)$**

You should plug (again) for $k=4$ and $k=5$ and sum them up. You'll get: $0.035$

**Step 5: conclusion:**

For any number:$0.035*6=0.21$.

Comment: This is the probability to have atbleast three of a specific value. You should multiply this by $6$, since it could be any value.

Comment: @ Alain Remillard oh. I added it in the answer (see timeline) not sure why I also took it off. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

No... it is not.

You must consider the *number of ways* you can get $3$ specific numbers (e.g., $1$) out of five rolls:  $(111xx),(x1x11),\ldots$, and likewise for four appearances, or five appearances.  This is governed by a binomial distribution.

For a given chosen number (e.g., a $1$), the number of ways you can get this is the probability of getting exactly three $1$s in known positions:  $\frac{1}{6} \cdot \frac{1}{6} \cdot \frac{1}{6}$.  But how many sets of three positions exist?  That is ${5 \choose 3} = 10$.  But for this to give *exactly* three $1$s, the other two positions must be *non* $1$s.  The probability of that is $\frac{5}{6} \cdot \frac{5}{6}$.

I'll let you multiply these out for yourself.

Next, if you allow getting *exactly* four $1$s, the above changes to $\frac{1}{6} \cdot \frac{1}{6} \cdot \frac{1}{6} \cdot \frac{1}{6}$ and ${5 \choose 4}$.  See why?

It is simple calculating the change of getting exactly five $1$s:  $\left( \frac{1}{6} \right)^5$

Then add them up.